# resize image and come up with php

Tags: php, image-resizing

I'm having the following problem, I'm uploading a picture, which varies greatly depending on the height and width of the device is taken (the picture is uploaded from a mobile device). I need to resize the image, rename it and upload it to my server. I made the following line of code and get the following error:

```
        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $porcentaje = 0.5;

        // Tipo de contenido
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        // Obtener nuevas dimensiones
        list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($nombre_archivo);
        $nuevo_ancho = $ancho * $porcentaje;
        $nuevo_alto = $alto * $porcentaje;

        // Redimensionar
        $imagen_p = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto);
        $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($nombre_archivo);
        imagecopyresampled($imagen_p, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
        if(move_uploaded_file ( $imagen_p , $destino )){

        }
```

Error : `move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

I was looking for some solutions but I have not managed to achieve this.

Comment: exactly like the error says. move() requires a STRING (e.g. the source/destination filenames). You're provided a GD handle... In your case, you don't want move **AT ALL** since your resampled image is NOT the original uploaded file. you just want `imagejpeg($imagen_p, $destino)`

Comment: @MarcB Man, absolutely right, you could leave it in response to mark it as correct. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like the error says: `move_uploaded_file()` requires a STRING (e.g. the source/destination filenames). You're provided a GD handle... In your case, you don't want move AT ALL since your resampled image is NOT the original uploaded file. You just want `imagejpeg($imagen_p, $destino)`